# Creation of an AMI from attached volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

In one of the AWS certification quizzes I met a question, where the proper answer states, that creation of an AMI from an attached EBS volume is not recommended and it is a bad practice.

Could someone give a more detailed explanation why it is so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any volume attached to an instance can be in an inconsistent state when the image is taken. This is why you should turn the instance off, image it, then turn it back on.

Most of the time it'll be fine if you snapshot / create an AMI of a running instance, but if you want to be sure it'll work you should stop it first.